Integral minimum inequality
Let $C$ be the class of all continuously differentiable functions $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=-1/3$ and $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = 0.$ Find $\min_{f \in C} \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{d}{dx} f(x) \right)^{2} dx.$
So I tried introducing a function that defines the integral of $f(x)$ and I always finished in a dead end where I couldn’t really go any further. I also used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to try finding a lower bound for the integral of $f’(x)$ but still couldn’t find what to do next. I didn’t even reach a step where I could use the conditions I’m given.
Any books you recommend that have similar problems? I found a book in french that has a lot of these but it doesn’t explain well enough.

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4892507/minimum-of-integral-involving-derivative-squared.

Idk how stack exchange works but the question was closed so i reposted it with edits

You can solve the problem using calculus of variations and Lagrange multipliers.

One way to learn how closed questions work is to read the box that says the question is closed, which describes (admittedly in a generic way) what to improve and includes a button to edit the question.

Note that, as $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f(0) = -\frac{1}{3}$, we have $f(x) = \int_0^x f’(t) \, dt - \frac{1}{3}$, so,
$$\begin{split}
0 &= \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 (\int_0^x f’(t) \, dt - \frac{1}{3}) \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 (\int_t^1 \, dx) f’(t) \, dt - \frac{1}{3}\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-t)f’(t) \, dt - \frac{1}{3}\\
&\leq (\int_0^1 (1-t)^2 \, dt)^{1/2}(\int_0^1 f’(t)^2 \, dt)^{1/2} - \frac{1}{3}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (\int_0^1 f’(t)^2 \, dt)^{1/2} - \frac{1}{3}
\end{split}$$
Where the equality on the third line uses Fubini’s theorem and the inequality on the fifth line uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Thus,
$$\int_0^1 f’(t)^2 \, dt \geq \frac{1}{3}$$
Recall that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality only achieves an equality when the two functions are constant multiples of each other, so we want to try functions $f$ with $f’(t) = C(1-t)$ for some constant $C$. Then,
$$f(x) = \int_0^x f’(t) \, dt - \frac{1}{3} = -\frac{C}{2}(1-x)^2 + \frac{C}{2} - \frac{1}{3}$$
So,
$$0 = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = -\frac{C}{6} + \frac{C}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{C - 1}{3}$$
Thus, $C = 1$ and $f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2 + \frac{1}{6}$. Then $f’(t) = 1-t$ and we have $\int_0^1 f’(t)^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{3}$. Hence,
$$\min_f \int_0^1 f’(t)^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{3}$$

why take 1 and t as the bouds for the dx integral and taking out the 1/3

1/3 is quite obvious i’m just being stupid but the bounds of the integral i still don’t get it

@Alilou The integral on the second line has $x$ from 0 to 1 and then $t$ from 0 to $x$. Treat it as a 2-d integral. Then the domain is ${(x, t) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]: t \leq x}$. Now if you integrate w.r.t. $t$ on the outside, then the range of $t$ is from 0 to 1 while the range of $x$ is from $t$ to 1. (Just draw a diagram of the integration domain and first slice it vertically, then horizontally.)

Yes i just noticed it seconds ago thank you man i really like the approach
